# How to highlight specific languages in Google Translate?

Tags: firefox, google-translate

I often translate between 5 languages in Google Translate. Is there any way to **highlight those specific languages** in the language selector dialogue? I'm not against using a Firefox-specific extension or userContent.css file.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/resarch efforts, including what you tried, as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén: Thank you for mentioning that. I have added an answer with resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight languages in Google Translate, use each language's language code in a CSS selector to target the element. To get the CSS selector, in Firefox right-click each language and press `Inspect Element`. There will be a `div` property called `data-language-code`. Note that code for each language to be highlighted.

In the [UserContent.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserContent.css) file, add the following code, using the appropriate language codes found in the previous step:

```
@-moz-document domain(translate.google.com) {
    /* ar en el iw ru */
    [data-language-code="ar"],
    [data-language-code="en"],
    [data-language-code="el"],
    [data-language-code="iw"],
    [data-language-code="ru"] {
        background-color:#ddffdd !important;
    }
}
```